# Cannot register new users with Devise: "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using MongoDB and Mongoid and am having issues letting users register. Whenever I try to register, I get the following:

> **NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create**
>
> `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`

The Application Trace in the error is empty, so I'm not sure where to begin to hunt for my error.

In case any of these are helpful:

- [user.rb](http://pastebin.com/NdS5rBk6)
- [new.html.erb](http://pastebin.com/f5cmtBc7), the form registration page
- [routes.rb](http://pastebin.com/dDrj81GW)
- [Request parameters](http://pastebin.com/RHprBu8G)
- [Framework error trace](http://pastebin.com/T2W54iGg) (Application Trace is empty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you're using Ruby 1.9.2 with Mongoid 3+, if so, you need to upgrade to 1.9.3 per [Mongoid docs](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/tips.html#ruby).

Comment: This looks like the issue -- investigating now.

Comment: Pardon my newbiness. Upgrading to Ruby 1.9.3 gives me syntax errors from within Mongoid: http://pastebin.com/zZXcGrra

Comment: Something might be wrong with your Ruby installation, but we can try creating a separate gemset for your project and see. Run `rvm use 1.9.3@your-project --create; bundle` in your project root then try again.

Answer (score 0):

At line 37 in [new.html.erb](http://pastebin.com/f5cmtBc7)

```
<div class="form-actions">
  <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
</div>
```

Is that what causing the problem? (`f.submit nil`)

Comment: No -- I changed it from nil to 'Sign up' and it stil gives the same error.